# Three.js: Could not initialise shader VALIDATE_STATUS: false, gl error [0] when loading example

Tags: three.js, shader

I have been looking at the examples provided along with the Three.js distribution and I get this error when I try to load the example webgl_materials_bumpmap_skin.html:

Could not initialise shader VALIDATE_STATUS: false, gl error [0]

I think it is a compilation error that has to do with the SkinSimple shader that is used in this particular example. Something similar happens in other examples as well.

For further reference, I'm using an ATI Radeon 45xx graphic card with the FGLRX driver under Debian. I have just downloaded the drivers to get my graphic card to support WebGL in this Linux distro and fglrxinfo shows that OpenGL 3.3 is installed.

I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: What about http://www.doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com/ where you are interested in OpenGL ES version.

Comment: The result is as follows: Version WebGL 1.0 (OpenGL ES 2.0 Chromium)   and  Shading Language Version WebGL GLSL ES 1.0 (OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0 Chromium)